# Ozonide v/s Ozonoid

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

Can anyone please clear the difference between ozonide and ozonoid.

I've already googled it but came up with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the term *ozonoide* now and then, both in German and English texts.

It was used for the the primary, as well as for the secondary ozonide. Interestingly, throughout these texts, you'll find this form only once or twice while the same authors mostly use the term *ozonide*!

While I'm roughly familiar with the Criegee mechanism, I'm not an expert on ozonolysis. Nevertheless, I'd dare to say there's no difference between these terms (at least, there seemingly was none for the authors) and I'd recommend to stay with the established term *ozonide*.